# Jenkins installation - Unable to create the home directory despite its existence and writeability

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I'm trying to install Jenkins on a Tomcat 7 container.

When I try to open the Jenkins web app I get following error:

```
Unable to create the home directory '/home/myuser/jenkins/work'. This is most 
likely a permission problem.

To change the home directory, use JENKINS_HOME environment variable or set 
the JENKINS_HOME system property. See Container-specific documentation for 
more details of how to do this.
```

Before starting Tomcat, I did `chmod uog+rwx /home/myuser/jenkins`. So, I suppose that Jenkins should be able to create a subdirectory there.

But obviously it can't.

How can I fix this problem?

**Update 1:**

`lt -lt` returns

`drwxrwxrwx 2 root     ec2-user    4096 Jun 23 10:25 jenkins`

for `/home/myuser/jenkins`. `/home/myuser/jenkins/work` doesn't exist because Jenkins is supposed to create it.

**Update 2:** Just tried to create the `work` directory and to run `chmod uog+rwx` on it. It didn't help.

**Update 3**: Additional information:

1. I need Jenkins in order to

   1. run lengthy tests in the night (fast unit tests are run before every `mvn install`, slow tests are executed every night) and
   2. save software quality metrics (checkstyle, PMD, FindBugs, unit test coverage etc.) over time.
2. I have only one machine available for that and there is a Tomcat7 container installed there already.
3. At the moment, I don't want to invest additional money into buying new machines.
4. The machine with the Tomcat7 container (and where I want Jenkins to be installed) is an Amazon EC2 microinstance (OS version is given below).

   $ cat /etc/*-release
   LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
   Amazon Linux AMI release 2013.03

**Update 4 (29.06.2013 13:34 MSK):** The output of `yum list` does not contain any Jenkins/Hudson package.

Comment: This may be to do with the permissions on the home directory - if the jenkins user can't see /home/myuser then it may not be able to write inside /home/myuser/jenkins. May be worth including ls -lt output for both /home/myuser and /home/myuser/jenkins to help people diagnose the issue for you.

Comment: @robjohncox I added the output of `ls -lt` in my update 1.

Comment: Could you show what ls -lt /home/myuser looks like too?

Comment: @robjohncox Yes - `drwx------ 5 myuser myuser 4096 Jun 23 10:25 myuser`.

Comment: I suppose that I should place the home directory of Jenkins to another place. Which directory is most suitable for this?

Comment: I have answered below. What you may want to do is actually create a separate jenkins user, with it's own home directory, run jenkins as that user and use it's home directory as `JENKINS_HOME`. If you are running Ubuntu, you could just install the Jenkins package, this is much easier to setup (there are probably similar Jenkins packages on other distributions too).

Comment: Does your Tomcat log provide any further details?

Answer (score 5):

If Tomcat is running as a separate user you will need to give execute permission to your home directory to that user - either by giving it to all or by creating a group especially for you and the tomcat user.

(UPDATE) More specifically: You say you already did `chmod uog+rwx /home/myuser/jenkins`, if Tomcat is not running asl 'myuser' it also needs execute permission on /home and on /home/myuser to be able to open /home/myuser/jenkins. If you are not picky about other users on the system opening your homedir you could allow this by: `chmod a+x /home/myuser`. (I'm assuming here the permissions for /home are already ok)

If you are running tomcat as 'myuser' the filsystem permissions look fine, but Tomcat's own permission system might be the problem as webapps are not allowed to touch the filesystem if the default settings of the security manager are on.

See: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tomcat

You don't specify more about your exact Tomcat/OS setup so I can't give exact details, but the fast way to find out if it's a security manager issue is to give AllPermission to you webapp. If you don't run in a safe environment it is advisable to only use that as a test, and setup only the really needed permissions later.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What additional information about my "Tomcat/OS" setup do you need (apart from what I wrote in item 3 of update 3 above) ?

Comment: Well you need to know where your tomcat configuration is located to edit the files mentioned on the page that I linked. Also - and maybe before researching into that option - you need to find out if tomcat is running as 'you' or as 'tomcat' or some other user. (check the output of 'ps aux' with tomcat running.)

Comment: I've updated my answer in case tomcat is not running as 'myuser'

Answer (score 4):

run these three commands

```
cd /usr/share/tomcat7

sudo mkdir .jenkins

sudo chown tomcat7:nogroup .jenkins
```

https://seleniumwithjavapython.wordpress.com/home/jenkins-installation/

Comment: This is the coolest and simplest answer, and the only one that works! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem may be that jenkins cannot see `/home/myuser`, and therefore it cannot access the jenkins folder inside this (even though it has write permissions in `/home/myuser/jenkins`, I believe the fact it can't read `/home/myuser` causes a problem).

Try running the below command and then see if Jenkins works after that:

```
chmod +r /home/myuser
```

Answer (score 0):

> @robjohncox Yes - drwx------ 5 myuser myuser 4096 Jun 23 10:25 myuser

you must add +x to this dir to make it possible for jenkins to access it's contents, to be precise whole path has to have +x enabled for everyone.

Also, what commands have you used to move it's home dir from default - possible error is somwhere there. Cheers, Piotr